# How to plot 3 models in one Figure in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm new with R and I have fit 3 models for my data as follows:

Model 1:  y = a(x) + b

```
lm1 = lm(data$CBI ~ data$dNDVI)
```

Model 2: y = a(x)2 + b(x) + c

```
lm2 <- lm(CBI ~ dNDVI + I(dNDVI^2), data=data)
```

Model 3: y = x(a|x| + b)–1

```
lm3 = nls(CBI ~ dNDVI*(a*abs(dNDVI) + b) - 1, start = c(a = 1.5, b = 2.7), data = data)
```

Now I would like to plot all these three models in R but I could not find the way to do it, can you please help me? I have tried with the first two models as follow and it work but I don't know how to add the Model 3 on it:

```
ggplot(data = data, aes(x = dNDVI, y = CBI)) + 
    geom_point() + 
    geom_smooth(method = lm, formula = y ~ x, size = 1, se = FALSE) +
    geom_smooth(method = lm, formula = y ~ x + I(x^2), size = 1, se = FALSE ) +
    theme_bw()
```

I also would like to add a legend which show 3 different colours or types of lines/curves for the 3 models as well. Can you please guide me how to make it in the figure?

Comment: ggplot2 has no method to plot `nls` models directly from `geom_smooth` (scroll down to "method" http://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_smooth.html). Fit the model separately, use a prediction function to create a dummy data set representing the fit line, then plot those data.

Comment: Thank you very much so I need to fit models separately first then use geom_lines with Predicted values right? Cheers

Comment: at least for `lm3`, just add that line to your `ggplot` call, the others should fit as you've plotted them - that's working fine now right?

Comment: I have tried with following codes:
ggplot(data = data, aes(x = dNDVI, y = CBI)) +
  geom_point() + geom_smooth(method = lm, formula = y ~ x, size = 1, se = FALSE) +
  geom_smooth(method = lm, formula = y ~ x + I(x^2), size = 1, se = FALSE ) + theme_bw() +
  geom_line(data=Xpred, aes(dNDVI, pred), col='green')

Comment: Can I make different types of line for each models and presenting them i a Legend for my figure pls? Thank you

Comment: RE: "I have tried..."  - and did it work? It's hard to help when we don't have your data (see: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Re the legends, that's quite a different issue, and maybe should be split into another question. Hard to answer here.

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

Using iris as a dummy set to represent the three models:

```
new.dat <- data.frame(Sepal.Length=seq(min(iris$Sepal.Length), 
                      max(iris$Sepal.Length), length.out=50)) #new data.frame to predict the fitted values for each model

m1 <- lm(Petal.Length ~ Sepal.Length, iris)
m2 <- lm(Petal.Length ~ Sepal.Length + I(Sepal.Length^2), data=iris)
m3 <- nls(Petal.Length ~ Sepal.Length*(a*abs(Sepal.Length) + b) - 1, 
        start = c(a = 1.5, b = 2.7), data = iris)

new.dat$m1.fitted <- predict(m1, new.dat)
new.dat$m2.fitted <- predict(m2, new.dat)
new.dat$m3.fitted <- predict(m3, new.dat)

new.dat <- new.dat %>% gather(var, val, m1.fitted:m3.fitted) #stacked format of fitted data of three models (to automatically generate the legend in ggplot)


ggplot(new.dat, aes(Sepal.Length, val, colour=var)) +
        geom_line()
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, Adam Quek. Thank you very much for your helps qith the codes. Im trying it now. Cheers

Comment: I run the last model and found the error as follow:
> lm3 <- nls(CBI ~ dBAI*(a*abs(dBAI) + b)^-1, 
+            start = c(a = 1.5, b = 2.7), data = data)
Error in nls(CBI ~ dBAI * (a * abs(dBAI) + b)^-1, start = c(a = 1.5, b = 2.7),  : 
  singular gradient

I have read all this afternoon how to define starting values and try bundred times but I did not get a luck for that

Do you think are there anyway to fix it pls? Thanks

Comment: Here's a rather [informative post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/160552/why-is-nls-giving-me-singular-gradient-matrix-at-initial-parameter-estimates). Unfortunately, I couldn't help you more without knowing what your data is about and what your data structure/ranges are.

Comment: Thank you very much, I am new user and I need to learn how to upload data to the post. Cheers